# GCC: -lxxx vs (libxxx.a or libxxx.so)

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

Is there some differences between `-lxxx` and `libxxx.a` or `libxxx.so` when compiling using GCC?

From the book **CSAPP** *Chapter 7: Linking*, it said:

> The `-lvector` argument is a shorthand for `libvector.a`

So the `-lxxx` is only a shorthand for `libxxx.a` or `libxxx.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a file /lib/libxxx.a and you want to link it to foo.o. Then gcc -L /lib -lxxx foo.o is equivalent to gcc foo.o /lib/libxxx.a. -L flag specifies your library search path. The difference between .a(archive) and .so(shared object) is static library vs shared library. Simply put, a static library is linked to your program at compilation time whereas a shared library is only loaded to memory at running time.